# Monthly Balance Calculator

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get my monthly balance calculator to work and I'm pretty sure I got everything set up correctly however I keep running into issues within the second .js library file where it's become not clickable...

for the date, I was hoping to get today's date if no date was entered

```js
"use strict";

var $ = function(id) { return document.getElementById(id); };

var updateDisplay = function () {
    var html = "<tr><th>Date</th><th>Amount</th><th>Balance</th></tr>";
    var html = html.concat("<tr><td></td><td></td><td>0</td></tr>");
    
    var count = getTransaction();
    var total = 0;
    
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        var trans = getTransaction(i);
        total = calculateBalance(trans["type"], trans["amount"], total);
        
        html = html.concat("<tr><td>", trans["dateDisplay"], "</td><td>", trans["amountDisplay"], "</td><td>", total, "</td></tr>");
    }
    $("transactions").innerHTML = html;

};

var add = function() {
    if ($("date").value === "") {
        addTransaction($("type").value, $("amount").value);
    } else {
        addTransaction($("type").value, $("amount").value, $("date").value);
    }
    updateDisplay();
};

window.onload = function () {
    $("add").onclick = add;
    updateDisplay();
};
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 480px;
    border: 3px solid blue;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
h1, h2 {
    color: blue;
}
h2 {
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
label {
    float: left;
    width: 11em;
    text-align: right;
    padding-bottom: .5em;
}
input, select {
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 0.75em;
}
table {
    width: 95%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 1em auto;
}
th, td {
    text-align: left;
}
th {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Monthly Balance Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="balance.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="library_balance.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="balance.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <h1>Monthly Balance Calculator</h1>
        <h2>Add Transaction</h2>
        <div>
            <label>Date:</label>
            <input type="text" id="date"><br>

            <label>Type:</label>
            <select id="type">
                <option value="deposit">Deposit</option>
                <option value="withdrawal">Withdrawal</option>
            </select><br>

            <label>Amount:</label>
            <input type="text" id="amount" value="100"><br>

            <label>&nbsp;</label>
            <input type="button" id="add" value="Add Transaction"><br>
        </div>

        <h2>Transactions</h2>
        <table id="transactions"></table>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

to change only these

```js
"use strict";

var transList = [];

var getTransaction = function(index) {

};

var addTransaction = function (type, amount, date) {
 var transaction = [];
 transaction["type"]   = type;
 transaction["amount"] = parseInt(amount);
 transaction["date"]   = date;
 transList.push(transaction);
};

var calculateBalance = function () {
 var balance = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < transList.length; i++) {
  if (transList[i]["type"] === "deposit") {
   balance = balance + transList[i]["amount"];
  } else {
   balance = balance - transList[i]["amount"];
  }
 }
 return balance;
};
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: Your code is not completed. in first js file you are initializing the count using getTransaction(index) function from second js file. It should be the size of the transList and getTransaction(index) should return transaction at that index.